# Cannot find module "@sendgrid/mail"

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I'm using the Sendgrid mail package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail) to send a test email using the Twilio Serveless functions. I have configured the module, specifying the correct version and module in the configure dashboard here. https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure but when I deploy my function and run it using the twilio cli, i get the error message,

"message":"Cannot find module '@sendgrid/mail'"

I find this weird since deploying the function manually under the Manage tab, https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage tab works like a gem. I'm I missing something?

Or does the serverless API doesn't currently support this? (the same package configurations work when I manually deploying the function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Twilio GUI Console based Functions are separate and distinct from the API based functions. You can find more detail here.

[Beta limitations, known issues and limits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api#beta-limitations-known-issues-and-limits)

You can add the npm module(s) using npm install , as detailed here.

[Twilio Serverless Toolkit - Deploy a Project](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/general-usage#deploy-a-project)

"Any dependency that is listed in the dependencies field in your package.json will automatically be installed in your deployment."

If you use the [Visual Studio Code](https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploy-twilio-functions-serverless-extension-vscode) approach, you can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
yarn add @sendgrid/mail
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
//ES6
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {}, console.error);
//ES8
(async () => {
  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toString());
  }
})();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.